# How to get a textfile to be showed in eclipse output?

Tags: java, eclipse, file-io, readfile

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.io.*;

public class Case1A {

    private static Scanner scnCode;

    public static void openFile() {
        try{
            scnCode = new Scanner(new File("employee.txt"));
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("You've got an error!");
        }
    }

    public static void readFile(String EmpCode){
        while(scnCode.hasNext()) {
            String EmployeeCode = scnCode.next();
            String EmployeeName = scnCode.next();

        System.out.printf("Employee Name: %s\n", EmployeeName);
        }
    }

    public static void closeFile() {
        scnCode.close();
    }


}
```

[image: TextFile]

I have a textfile just like on the post, and the program needs to get the name that corresponds to the specific code. For example, I put A11-0002 and the program output will be Lamina, Seth M. How can I get that name for that especific code? 
My code is on the above, and I think that the wrong code is in the readFile() method and I cant get the correct code.

Comment: What's the problem with your code? Where's your `main` method?

Comment: Consider doing `EmployeeName = scnCode.nextLine()` to grab the entire name.

Comment: personally I would read the whole line and then split based upon whatever chars are between code and name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to code what you wanted your code to do:-

**Input:-**
 A11-11

**Output:-**
Employee Name:- Suraj Kumar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgZwb.png)

**Test Data:-
A11-11 Kumar,Suraj
A22-11 Laal,Baal
A33-33 Teri,Warner**

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.*;


    public class ParseText {
static LinkedList<Employee> list = new LinkedList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    readFile();
    getEmployee("A11-11"); //This is for test, you get the
                            //read the id from command line as well

     }
public static void readFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file=new File("C:\\test\\textTest.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);    
    String temp;
    while(sc.hasNext()){
        temp = sc.nextLine();
        //System.out.println("temp "+ temp);
        String[] s = temp.split(" ");
        String[] name = s[1].split(",");
        String id = s[0];
        String lastName = name[0];
        String firstName = name[1];
        Employee emp = new Employee(firstName, lastName, id);
        list.add(emp);
    }
    sc.close();
     }

public static void getEmployee(String id) {
    Iterator<Employee> itr = list.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        Employee emp = itr.next();
        if(emp.id.equals(id)){
            System.out.println("Employee Name:- "+emp.firtName+" "+emp.lastName);
        }
    }
}
    }

    class Employee {
String firtName;
String lastName;
String id;

Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String id) {
    this.firtName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirtName() {
    return firtName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}
    }
```

Comment: what is the meaning of iterator? what its purpose? i am just new in programming!

Comment: First of if you are new to programming i would suggest you to read Java oracle tutorials [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ )
In Java collections we have an Iterator interface [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)

Comment: Iterator interface has 3 methods hasNext(), next() and remove(). 
Generally only hasNext() and next() is implemented in various collections like 
LinkedList, hasMap() and so on. Now if you have an iterator, 
it works almost in the same way how scanner works. With hasNext(), 
you can check whether next element is present in the collection or not.

Comment: And with next(), you can access that element. 
For example we have a linkedList have following elements:-
 [a, b, c, d, e, f]. Now if you get an iterator over the 
list iter.hasNext() will check whether any element present in linked list
 starting from beginning. in this case we have "a" as the first element. 
hasNext will return true. Now next() will return "a". Hope it clears.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use `BufferedReader` to read contents from file.
2. Find the position of first space character.
3. Divide the line from that index using `str.substring()`. Now you have 2 Strings.
4. You can put this key value pair in a Map.
5. Everytime you need value of a key in a map, just get it using `employees.get("A11-0003")`.

Output:

```
Roda, Ronamy M.
```

Code:

```
package apachecommonstest;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Case1A {
    private static Map<String, String> employees = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        setEmployeeData();
        System.out.println(employees.get("A11-0003"));
    }

    //set employee data from file to Map employees
    private static void setEmployeeData() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line[] = new String[2];
        int spaceIndex;
        try {
            String sCurrentLine;
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\fakelocation\\employee.txt"));
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                spaceIndex = sCurrentLine.indexOf(" ");
                line[0] = sCurrentLine.substring(0, spaceIndex);
                line[1] = sCurrentLine.substring(spaceIndex+1);
                employees.put(line[0], line[1]);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {} finally {
            if(br!=null)br.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will have issues if the line record has just single space after emp code. Example - a line record like
A11-230<space>

Comment: I've just given a place to start. There can be many modifications that can be done in this code as according to varying input; like (i) Trimming the result of substring, (ii) placing `try-catch` block on `line[1] = sCurrentLine.substring(spaceIndex+1);` to look for `NullPointerException` etc...

Answer (score 2):

1) Read file using fileinputstream and then create memory of file using buffer reader.
2) Read line in file using read line.
3) I created like separating line using substring and then comparing.

Main:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Please Enter: ");
            String in = scanner.next();
            TextFile t = new TextFile();
            t.Employee(in);
        }
```

Program:

```
public class TextFile {
    public void Employee(String in) {
        FileInputStream f;
        try {
            f = new FileInputStream("D:/sample1.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(f));
            String strLine;
            int space;
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                space = strLine.indexOf(" ");
                String s=strLine.substring(0,space);
                String s1=strLine.substring(space+1);
                if(in.equals(s)){
                    System.out.println(s1.trim());
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

[image: Output]

[image: sample text file]

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the file and its line records based on field separator, and store the details in map - key as empcode and value as employee details. This way, you can fetch the employeedetails from passing empcode as key to map.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Case1A {
    private static String LINE_SEPERATOR = "\\t";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file=new File("C:\\temp\\Employee.txt");
        Map<String, String> employeeMap = new HashMap<>();
        String lineData = null;
        String[] empDetails = new String[10];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            lineData = sc.nextLine();
            empDetails = lineData.split(LINE_SEPERATOR);
            if(empDetails != null && empDetails.length >= 2){
                employeeMap.put(empDetails[0],empDetails[1]);
            }
        }
        sc.close();
        System.out.println(employeeMap.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the meaning of the map? what it's purpose?

Comment: i am just new in programming.

Comment: Refer here - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html
It has key, value combination and key is unique. Imagine like a excel table with two columns - much similar to that.

Comment: how about the throws exception code, what its purpose?

Comment: Start learning tutorials of Java - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/
Please mark as answered(ticked), if the above answered the query